# Get values only within the shape geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have a big dataset with geo data. I want to extact data only related to the part of the city. So I need to create a shape and check whether or not my point is there.

I tried to work with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608107/11852936):

## POINTS

1)

```
turin.head() = 

       latitude     longitude   
    0   44.9125     7.7432  
    21  45.0764     7.5249  
    22  45.0764     7.5249  
    23  45.0755     7.5248 
    24  45.0718     7.5236
```

2)

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(turin.longitude,turin.latitude)]
turin_point = gpd.GeoDataFrame(turin,crs=crs,geometry=geometry)
turin_point.head()


    latitude    longitude   geometry
0   44.9125     7.7432  POINT (7.74320 44.91250)
21  45.0764     7.5249  POINT (7.52490 45.07640)
22  45.0764     7.5249  POINT (7.52490 45.07640)
23  45.0755     7.5248  POINT (7.52480 45.07550)
24  45.0718     7.5236  POINT (7.52360 45.07180)
```

## BORDERS

1)

```
border.head()

    longitude   latitude    
0   7.577835    45.041828   
1   7.579849    45.039877   
2   7.580106    45.039628   
3   7.580852    45.038576   
4   7.580866    45.038556
```

2)

```
geometry2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(border.longitude,border.latitude)]
border_point = gpd.GeoDataFrame(border,crs=crs,geometry=geometry2)
border_point.head() = 

        longitude   latitude    geometry
    0   7.577835    45.041828   POINT (7.57783 45.04183)
    1   7.579849    45.039877   POINT (7.57985 45.03988)
    2   7.580106    45.039628   POINT (7.58011 45.03963)
    3   7.580852    45.038576   POINT (7.58085 45.03858)
    4   7.580866    45.038556   POINT (7.58087 45.03856)
```

## Then according to [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608107/11852936):

```
turin_final= border_point.geometry.unary_union
within_turin = turin_point[turin_point.geometry.within(turin_final)]
```

> IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: You have two layer of points. Point within point does not make sense, it will never give you meaningful result. You want your border layer to be a polygon?

Comment: @martinfleis I want to check which points from `turin` are located in `border` and save them.

Comment: But your border is a set of points, it has no area. If your set of points is supposed to be a Polygon, you have to generate it out of those points.

Comment: @martinfleis So I am asking this

Comment: Not knowing the correct order of points, you may get incorrect polygon. But you can try `turin_final = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border_point.geometry])` instead your `turin_final` line.

Comment: @martinfleis I guess you have solved the issue. post it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find points within your border, the border itself needs to be a Polygon, not another set of points. If coords of border points are in the correct order, you can try replacing last two lines with these:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

turin_final = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border_point.geometry])
within_turin = turin_point[turin_point.geometry.within(turin_final)]
```

Often that is not the case, but as I understood from your comments, it has resolved your issue.